# How Do I Override Checkout HTML Templates

Tags: magento2, checkout, template

I am trying to update the html for the cart that gets displayed in the sidebar on the checkout.

I have copied:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary

to my theme:

> my_theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary

I have made changes to the html templates within the summary directory however the checkout page seems to be loading the default HTML templates?

How I can override the templates for the checkout?

Thanks

Comment: Run below commands after copied the file in "my_theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary"

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can override vendor template files by following method

Copy the file from vendor and paste the file in

> my_theme/Magento_Checkout/template/summary

Hope this will work